# Accessing to fields of all objects in list

Tags: java, list, java-8, field

I have a `List<Foo>`, where `Foo` is a `class` containing a `String` field named `name`. I want to know if the `List` contains a `Foo` object with it's `name` equal to `"bar"`.

Is this possible without iterating over each object and testing them one by one ?

I'm using Java 8.

Comment: In short, no. You can make the code look nicer in Java 8, but in effect it will go through the list.

Comment: you could never say the object isn't the one you are looking for, unless you check it. therefore you have to check every object's name in your list.

Comment: @NimrodArgov
Sure. What I wanted to do is to do it without a for loop.

Comment: @Franckyi the solution is still a loop, just one you don't see

Comment: @Eugene I know, I just wanted a one-liner for that instead of typing a loop.

Comment: Be careful here: what is the point of using an abstraction you are not familiar with? Are you really comfortable using code you could not write yourself? I am just wondering about your motivation to not use something you are familiar with... And instead picking up something that you have not seen before? What if that other code gives a problem at some point? Do you feel comfortable debugging it then?

Comment: @GhostCat I was curious to know if it was possible to do what I asked in a compact way using Java 8 features. Of course, I have to learn better how to use method references and lambas expressions if I want to use this code in production.

Comment: Okay, that is a reasonable approach. My vote for that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a parallel stream to return an `Optional<String>` which may or may not be empty, depending on if "bar" exists as an attribute for a `Foo` object in the `List<Foo>`:

```
list.parallelStream()
    .map(Foo::getName)
    .filter(s -> s.equals("bar"))
    .findAny();
```

This still iterates through the `List<Foo>`, but it is, at worst, O(n / # of threads used)

Another option would be to sort the list by the `name` attribute and then do a binary search, but it would most likely still cost a bit to sort it.

Comment: Looks like what I wanted. Thanks !

Comment: Please note: you probably need thousands of elements in that List to make up for the overhead required to pull up that parallel stream. And an argument about big O like this... Bizarre. Before you say yes and adapt this solution : measure it. For small lists this is more expensive than serial processing.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the information. I'll use it in the right situation.

Comment: Or `Predicate.isEqual("bar")`.

Comment: Or `"bar"::equals`. Though, if you only want to know *if* there is a match, `list.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getName().equals("bar"))` would be sufficient. By they way “O(n / # of threads used)” is still O(n).